# Existence everywhere of integrand in Fubini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f\in L(A,\mu_x\otimes\mu_y)$ be a summable function on $A\subset X\times Y$ where $(X\times Y,\mu_x\otimes\mu_y)$ is the product of measure spaces $(X,\mu_x)$ and $(Y,\mu_y)$. Then Fubini's theorem says that $$\int_A f(x,y) d\mu_x\otimes\mu_y=\int_X\Bigg(\int_{A_x}f(x,y)d\mu_y\Bigg) d\mu_x=\int_Y\Bigg(\int_{A_y}f(x,y)d\mu_x\Bigg) d\mu_y.$$

From the [proof](http://librarum.org/book/10022/184) in Kolmogorov-Fomin's *Introductory Real Analysis* it seems to me to understand, or misunderstand, that the integrands $\int_{A_x}f(x,y)d\mu_y$ and $\int_{A_y}f(x,y)d\mu_x$ exist everywhere. Nevertheless, further in their original *Элементы теории функций и функционального анализа*, when talking about the Fredholm operator, it is said (p. 461 [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)) that $\int_{[a,b]}K(s,t)\varphi(t)d\mu_t$, where $\varphi\in L_2[a,b]$ and $K\in L_2([a,b]^2)$, exists for *almost* all $s\in[a,b]$.

Do $\int_{A_x}f(x,y)d\mu_y$ and $\int_{A_y}f(x,y)d\mu_x$ respectively exist for all $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ or do not they? I thank you anybody for any answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the inner integral exists only almost everywhere, if $f$ can assume positive, **as well as negative** values.

To see this, consider e.g.

$$
f(x,0) = 1 \text{ if } x >0,\\
f(x,0) = -1 \text{ if } x<0,\\
f(x,y)=0 \text{ otherwise}. 
$$

Then $f$ is integrable w.r.t. the 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure (on the Borel sigma algebra, which is the product of the 1-dimensional Borel sigma algebras), because it vanishes almost everywhere.

But for $y=0$, the inner integral

$$
\int f(x,0)\, dx
$$
does not exist.

You do not have this problem for $f \geq 0$, but there the inner integral can be infinite on a null set.

Comment: Now it's clear: the linked proof, without loss of generality, only applies to $f^+$. Thank you so much!